# Is it possible to extend react table v8 API using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, extend, react-table

I am trying to extend react-table v8 api with custom functions.

In the docs are saying that it is possible to:

```
declare module '@tanstack/table-core' {
  interface TableMeta<TData extends RowData> {
    someCustomFunction: () => boolean;
  }
}
```

and later we can access this function though:
`table.options.meta.someCustomFunction()`

I am looking for a way to extend `table` itself.

`table.someCustomFunction()`

but when I try

```
declare module '@tanstack/table-core' {
  interface Table<TData extends RowData> {
    someCustomFunction: () => boolean;
  }
}
```

typescript is complaining:

`{headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {...`
Parameter '**header**' implicitly has an 'any' type.

`{table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (....`
Parameter '**headerGroup**' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import `import "@tanstack/react-table";`

```
import "@tanstack/react-table";

declare module '@tanstack/table-core' {
  interface Table<TData extends RowData> {
    someCustomFunction: () => boolean;
  }
}
```